# Expand dataframe based on column values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like so:

```
    Title Female Male Asian HispanicLatino White
1   Title1      2    3     1              1     3
2   Title2      1    5    NA              1     5
3   Title3     NA    2    NA             NA     2
```

I want to expand this out so that there are two rows for Female in Title 1, and three Male, as well as expanding the other columns (I have many more columns).

I've tried various different things, and the following technically works but is not ideal.

```
    df[is.na(df)] <- 0

    dfM <- uncount(df, df$Male)
    dfM$Sex <- "M"


    dfF <- uncount(df, df$Female)
    dfF$Sex <- "F"

    df <- rbind.fill(dfF, dfM)
```

Which produces

```
   Title Female Male Asian  HispanicLatino   White Sex
1    Title1      2    3     1              1     3   F
2    Title1      2    3     1              1     3   F
3    Title2      1    5     0              1     5   F
4    Title1      2    3     1              1     3   M
5    Title1      2    3     1              1     3   M
6    Title1      2    3     1              1     3   M
7    Title2      1    5     0              1     5   M
8    Title2      1    5     0              1     5   M
9    Title2      1    5     0              1     5   M
10   Title2      1    5     0              1     5   M
11   Title2      1    5     0              1     5   M
12   Title3      0    2     0              0     2   M
13   Title3      0    2     0              0     2   M
```

Curious to see if there is a much easier way to do this.

Here is some data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Title = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Title1", 
"Title2", "Title3"), class = "factor"), Female = c(2L, 1L, NA
), Male = c(3L, 5L, 2L), Asian = c(1L, NA, NA), HispanicLatino = c(1L, 
1L, NA), White = c(3L, 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("Title", "Female", 
"Male", "Asian", "HispanicLatino", "White"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Can you please show the expected output

Comment: @akrun, just added that in now.

Comment: I get 12 rows from that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be `map` to loop over the columns to expand after `replace`ing the NA with 0 while creating a `.id` column ('Sex')

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(setNames(c("Female", "Male"), c("F", "M")), ~ 
       df %>%
           mutate_at(vars(.x), replace_na, 0) %>% 
           uncount(!! rlang::sym(.x), .remove = FALSE), .id = 'Sex') %>%
       mutate_at(3:6, replace_na, 0)
#   Sex  Title Female Male Asian HispanicLatino White
#1    F Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#2    F Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#3    F Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#4    M Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#5    M Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#6    M Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#7    M Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#8    M Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#9    M Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#10   M Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#11   M Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#12   M Title3      0    2     0              0     2
#13   M Title3      0    2     0              0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, we can use `rep` to repeat number of rows after converting `NA`s to 0.

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0 #Don't use this line if NA needed in final output.
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), rowSums(df[c("Female", "Male")])), ]

#     Title Female Male Asian HispanicLatino White
#1   Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#1.1 Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#1.2 Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#1.3 Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#1.4 Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#2   Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#2.1 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#2.2 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#2.3 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#2.4 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#2.5 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#3   Title3      0    2     0              0     2
#3.1 Title3      0    2     0              0     2
```

Since in the final output all `NA`s are converted to 0 we replace `NA` to 0 here. If we want `NA`s to be kept as `NA` in the final output we can use `na.rm = TRUE` in `rowSums` instead.

If the order of rows is important we can use repeat individually. We can also delete rownames.

```
row_inds <- seq_len(nrow(df))
df1 <- df[c(rep(row_inds, df$Female), rep(row_inds, df$Male)), ]
rownames(df1) <- NULL
df1

#   Title Female Male Asian HispanicLatino White
#1  Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#2  Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#3  Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#4  Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#5  Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#6  Title1      2    3     1              1     3
#7  Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#8  Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#9  Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#10 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#11 Title2      1    5     0              1     5
#12 Title3      0    2     0              0     2
#13 Title3      0    2     0              0     2
```